# TimeSliderChoropleth with autoplay

Tags: folium

I like the controls of the `HeatMapWithTime` plugin a lot. But the `TimeSliderChoropleth` plugin is much more appropriate to the visualization I want to do. The thing I'm missing the most with these more minimalistic controls is a play button, like the autoplay in the `HeatMapWithTime` plugin. I could imagine that it would be fairly easy to implement, but unfortunately, I have no experience with d3 or JavaScript.

Is there a way of implementing this feature using Python?